# mail() MIME attachment just says file location in the file

Tags: php, html

I have an issue where the code below sends the attachment but the file has the correct name but the contents are just the uploads/name of file in it. Why is the code below doing that?

Thanks

```
        $name_of_uploaded_file= basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
        $uploaddir = "uploads/";

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir.$_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
        $separator = md5(time());
        $eol = PHP_EOL;
        $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($uploaddir.$name_of_uploaded_file));
        $to = 'ccotrainingrequests@walgreens.com';
        $subject = 'New Training Request Ticket #' . $ticketid;
        $message = 'Ticket #' . $ticketid . ' Has Been Submitted';
        $headers = "From:  ".$to.$eol;
        $headers .= "MIME-Version:  1.0".$eol;
        $headers .= "Content-Type:  multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";
        $body = "--".$separator.$eol;
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:  7bit".$eol.$eol;
        $body .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol;
        $body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
        $body .= "Content-Type:  text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:  8bit".$eol.$eol;
        $body .= $message.$eol;
        $body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
        $body .= "Content-Type:  application/octet-stream; name=\"".$name_of_uploaded_file."\"".$eol;
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:  base64".$eol;
        $body .= "Content-Disposition:  attachment".$eol.$eol;
        $body .= $attachment.$eol;
        $body .= "--".$separator."--";

        mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Comment: When you say "sends the attachment" what do you mean? Does the file exist on your server where you're pointing?

Comment: It does exist and I can open it with the original contents inside it.  But when it gets sent in an email the only contents of the file are the uploads/filename in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not reading the contents of your file on the $attachment... line of code, you are `chuck_split`ting the name of the file.  That's why only the name is getting sent.  You need to do something like an `fread()` of the file and then `chunk_split` that.